# How could Powershell debugger can modify runtime behavior?

Tags: powershell, debugging

I reduced the code at its minimum to highlight one very strange issue from Powershell

Same for pwsh 5.1.22000.282 and 7.2.2.

Code:

```sh
$outlook = new-object -com Outlook.Application;
$namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI");
$inputFolderObj=$namespace.Folders.Item('user@domain.com').Folders.Item('temp')
$scope = $inputFolderObj.FolderPath
$filter = ""
$search = $outlook.AdvancedSearch("'$scope'", $filter, $True)
$search.Results.Count
```

on CLI :

```sh
PS C:\dummyfolder> .\test.ps1
0
PS C:\dummyfolder> .\test.ps1 # reproductible
0
PS C:\dummyfolder> Set-PSBreakpoint -Line 7 -Script .\test.ps1 | out-null
PS C:\dummyfolder> .\test.ps1
Passage en mode débogage. Utilisez h ou ? pour obtenir de l'aide.

Appuyez sur Point d'arrêt de ligne sur « C:\Udummyfolder\test.ps1:7 »

Au caractère C:\dummyfolder\test.ps1:7 : 1
+ $search.Results.Count
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[DBG]: PS C:\dummyfolder>> c
1
```

Is it a bug? Do I miss something here? Thanks,

---

**Edit 17.03.2022** - did some tests. It appears that having a breakpoint at line 7 and only fetching results doesn't yield '1' every time. Relaunching `$search`, then `$search.Results` several times at the breakpoint finally yields '1'. It can therefore be a problem w/ the Marshall interop of Outlook, but if anyone knows why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

Marshall Object dealing with Outlook is loading asynchronously.

We may add a certain pause before result Counting to get object. Debug breakpoint was silently introducing this extra-step.

Final code:

```sh
    $outlook = new-object -com Outlook.Application;
    $namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI");
    $inputFolderObj=$namespace.Folders.Item('user@domain.com').Folders.Item('temp')
    $scope = $inputFolderObj.FolderPath
    $filter = ""
    $search = $outlook.AdvancedSearch("'$scope'", $filter, $True)
    Start-Sleep 10
    $search.Results.Count
```